# Misunderstanding a problem with Portal in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Creating simple app using React and Redux.

The point is to get photos from the server and show them. If you click on the photo you get modal window with bigger photo and comments. I use Portal in my Modal component.

Code form ModalContainer

```
import React from 'react'
import { closeModal } from '../redux/actions/actions'
import Modal from '../components/modal/Modal'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const ModalContainer = () => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: '',
    comment: '',
  })
  const { photo, isOpen } = useSelector(({ modal }) => modal);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    }
    return () => {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'
    }
  }, []);

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value, name } }) => {
    setUser({
      ...user,
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  const modalClose = () => {
    dispatch(closeModal())
  }

  const onOverlayClick = (e) => {
    dispatch(closeModal())
    e.stopPropagation()
  }

  const onModalClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
  }

  const pushComment = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios
      .post(
        `https://boiling-refuge-66454.herokuapp.com/images/${photo.id}/comments`,
        { name: user.name, comment: user.comment, date: Date.parse(String(new Date())) }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      setUser({
        name: '',
        comment: '',
      })  
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      onClick={modalClose}
      onLayoutClick={onOverlayClick}
      onModalClick={onModalClick}
      src={photo.url}
      comments={photo.comments}
      name={user.name}
      comment={user.comment}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onSubmit={pushComment}
    />
  )
}

export default ModalContainer
```

Code for Portal

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Portal = ({ children }) => {
  
  const el = document.createElement('div');

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(el);
    } 
  }, [])

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, el);
}

export default Portal
```

Code for Modal

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import './Modal.scss'
import close from '../../images/close.png'
import Input from '../input/Input'
import Button from '../button/Button'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Portal from '../portal/Portal'

const Modal = ({
  onClick,
  onChange,
  onSubmit, 
  src,
  comments,
  name,
  comment,
  onModalClick,
  onLayoutClick,
}) => {
  return (
    <Portal>
      <div className="modal__layout" onClick={onLayoutClick}>
        <div className="modal__window" onClick={onModalClick}>
          <div className="modal__content">
            <div className="modal__item">
              <img src={src} alt={src} />
              <div className="modal__comments">
                <div className="modal__comment">
                  {comments.map((comment) => {
                    return (
                      <Fragment key={comment.id}>
                        <p>{new Date(comment.date).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                        <p>{comment.text}</p>
                      </Fragment>
                    )
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <Input
                name="name"
                type="text"
                value={name}
                placeholder="Ваше имя"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
              <Input
                name="comment"
                type="text"
                value={comment}
                placeholder="Ваш комментарий"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
              <Button>Оставить комментарий</Button>
            </form>
            <img className="close" src={close} alt="close" onClick={onClick} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Portal>
  )
}

Modal.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  onModalClick: PropTypes.func,
  src: PropTypes.string,
  comments: PropTypes.array,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  comment: PropTypes.string,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  onLayoutClick: PropTypes.func,
}

Modal.defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {},
  onModalClick: () => {},
  src: '',
  comments: [],
  onChange: () => {},
  name: '',
  comment: '',
  onSubmit: () => {},
  onLayoutClick: () => {},
}

export default Modal
```

The problem is when I open modal window with bigger photo and comments and try to fill inputs or to press button without text in inputs to push a comment to a server, modal window closes and doesn't react at all. But without Portal component it works perfectly. What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by doesnot react at all ?

Comment: First thing, its a bad practice playing with DOM in react app

Comment: @simbathesailor, I mean you can't open modal window

Comment: @Rajesh, any advise then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do something like this. Let me know if this brings in improvement in the results.

```
// Code form ModalContainer 

<Modal
   
      onClick={modalClose}
      onLayoutClick={onOverlayClick}
      onModalClick={onModalClick}
      src={photo.url}
      comments={photo.comments}
      name={user.name}
      comment={user.comment}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onSubmit={pushComment}
   isOpen={isOpen}
    />

// Modal code
const Modal = ({
  onClick,
  onChange,
  onSubmit, 
  src,
  comments,
  name,
  comment,
  onModalClick,
  onLayoutClick,
  isOpen
}) => {
  return (
    <Portal isOpen={isOpen}>
      <div className="modal__layout" onClick={onLayoutClick}>
        <div className="modal__window" onClick={onModalClick}>
          <div className="modal__content">
            <div className="modal__item">
              <img src={src} alt={src} />
              <div className="modal__comments">
                <div className="modal__comment">
                  {comments.map((comment) => {
                    return (
                      <Fragment key={comment.id}>
                        <p>{new Date(comment.date).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                        <p>{comment.text}</p>
                      </Fragment>
                    )
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <Input
                name="name"
                type="text"
                value={name}
                placeholder="Ваше имя"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
              <Input
                name="comment"
                type="text"
                value={comment}
                placeholder="Ваш комментарий"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
              <Button>Оставить комментарий</Button>
            </form>
            <img className="close" src={close} alt="close" onClick={onClick} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Portal>
  )
}

Modal.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  onModalClick: PropTypes.func,
  src: PropTypes.string,
  comments: PropTypes.array,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  comment: PropTypes.string,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  onLayoutClick: PropTypes.func,
}


// Portal Code



import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Portal = ({ children, isOpen }) => {
  
  const [elem, setElem] = useState(null)
 
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(el); 
    setElem(el)
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(el);
    }
  }, [])
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if(isOpen) {
  //      document.body.appendChild(el); 
  //   }
  //  return () => {
  //     document.body.removeChild(el);
  //   } 
  // }, [isOpen])
  

  if(!el || !isOpen) return null
  if(el && isOpen) return  ReactDOM.createPortal(children, el);

}

export default Portal
```